# Does anything happen to serial downvoters?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Just had 4 separate questions downvoted in quick succession - what happens to those who do it?

And how can we find out who is responsible? Or at least get confirmation that something happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a really good write up over at Meta Stack Exchange on [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

In your particular case the votes should be reversed within 24 hours.

Comment: That's a good write up as you say, thanks. And I can see the reasoning cheers.